# I am trying to remember a word/phrase that is often used to describe backwards and heavy handed laws

Tags: terminology, synonyms, descriptive-grammar

I am having the darndest time trying to remember this word/phrase. I have seen it used many times over the years to describe laws, rules, and policies that are usually very heavy handed and backwards thinking.

Laws that don't really understand the issue they are trying to solve and instead take an almost vindictive approach to solving problems.

For the life of me I can't remember and I keep trying to say it is Gregorian. But I know that is not right.

Does anyone know what I am talking about? I have seen it a lot on [techdirt.com](http://techdirt.com).

Comment: Draconian? This refers to heavy-handedness, not necessarily backwards. He laid down the first written constitution of Athens.

Comment: A *reactionary* law, in opposition to a revolutionary law, errs away from current trends to those of the past.

Comment: Heavy-handed is... *punitive*?   A fun one for backwards is *antediluvian*.

Comment: I have not seen that word before @stevesilva. Though I made this request for a comment I was leaving to an article. So I would need a word that can be understood by the masses.

Comment: Gregorian is usually used in reference to the Calendar. Secondarily, in reference to the "Chants", a type of sacred, unaccompanied and free formed singing. After that, it's in reference to one of the Popes named Gregory and anything that he oversaw, instated, or was Pope during.

Comment: @fredsbend Yeah, I know that. That is why I knew it was wrong. Just one of those times where one word reminds you of another in meaning or in some other relation. In this case both in sound and the reference to something long ago.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Draconian (pertaining to Draco)

> The laws [Draco] laid down were the first written constitution of Athens. So that no one would be unaware of them, they were posted on wooden tablets... thus made known to all literate citizens. <sub><sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_%28lawgiver%29)</sup></sub>

The laws were particularly harsh. The punishment for even minor offenses, e.g. "stealing a cabbage", was death.

> One thing we must do is rethink the draconian collection policies that leave vulnerable students with nowhere to turn. - NYT

Answer (score 23):

> [draconian](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/draconian):
> very strict and cruel
>
> [Longman]

So named for the Greek lawgiver [Draco](http://www.britannica.com/biography/Draco-Greek-lawgiver):

> Athenian lawgiver whose harsh legal code punished both trivial and serious crimes in Athens with death—hence the continued use of the word draconian to describe repressive legal measures.
>
> [Britannica]

Answer (score 5):

While draconian would have been my 1st choice, **Puritanical** also comes to mind

> **[Puritanical](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/puritanical)**-
>   very strict in moral or religious matters, often excessively so; rigidly austere

Comment: I thought of this one too, but it didn't quite encompass what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not a perfect fit, but "arcane" comes to mind.  This is often used to describe very old laws that are never enforced, but remain on the books, and make no sense in current society.

> [arcane](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arcane) (adj) known or understood by very few; mysterious; secret; obscure; esoteric

Answer (score 5):

If you want to focus more on the "backwards" than the "heavy handed" part of the question, I would recommend using the term "Byzantine". It is often used to refer to layers of bureaucratic red tape and obscure laws.

Answer (score 3):

Although not exactly the word you're looking for another choice is **onerous**. According to [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onerous%20law%2CDraconian%20law%2C%20draconian%20law%2C%20Onerous%20law&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conerous%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDraconian%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraconian%20law%3B%2Cc0), use of the term "onerous law" has at times been not too far distant from "Draconian law" or "draconian law". Most recently, "draconian" seems to be the winner, with the properly capitalized variant losing ground to it.

**[onerous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onerous)**

> 1 :  involving, imposing, or constituting a burden :  troublesome
>
> 2 :  having legal obligations that outweigh the
> advantages

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, **draconian** fits if the the laws are heavy handed and authoritarian.

You might also consider **archaic**

> **archaic** *adjective* old and no longer useful

(Meriam-Webster)

This would capture the 'backwards thinking' part of what you're looking for.

eg.

> Laws forbidding gay marriage are an *archaic* throwback to when we based our morality on The Bible.
>
> The War on Drugs is an *archaic* and draconian set of laws created in a time when we had less understanding the nature of addiction and human psychology, and less tolerant attitudes.

Answer (score 1):

"Regressive" - moving things backwards, arguably to a worse state that the current one.

Answer (score 0):

An Afrikaans word has been accepted into English: verkrampte

This word aptly describes the obtuse and unenlightened mentality that accompanies extreme conservatism; cramped and restricted. The opposite, which is now also accepted English is verligte, which means enlightened.

See http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/verkrampte, http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/verkrampte

Comment: Judging from the linked definitions, _verkrampte_ seem to have been accepted into English only in the very narrow context of views on apartheid in South Africa. I haven't seen either _verkrampte_ or _verligte_ used in U.S. English, and I would be especially concerned that _verkrampte_ might be confused by readers or listeners with [_verklempt_ ](http://www.yiddishslangdictionary.com/word/351/verklempt), which is a Yiddish word but I suspect is more common among North American English speakers than either _verkrampte_ or _verligte_.

Answer (score 0):

**Hammurabic**?  The Code of Hammurabi was famous, of course, for the first articulation of the *lex talionis* ("an eye for an eye", etc.).

Answer (score 0):

*Unconstitutional* comes to mind and was also on the link you posted. 

I checked: 
 http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/heavy%20handed

The following entry might hold the answer.:

"Main Entry: tyrannical

Part of Speech: adjective

Definition: despotic, oppressive

Synonyms: authoritarian, autocratic, brutal, cruel, demanding, dictatorial, domineering, harsh, heavy-handed, ironhanded, mean, overbearing, repressive, ruthless, totalitarian, tough, unjust"

I hope that helps.